# Problem with bubble sorting numbers from a list then into an array in c++

Tags: c++

I need to write a program which reads a list of numbers and the prints the array twice, before and after sorting.

Here is the list of the 51 numbers
(50 28 84 41 52 22 22 74 33 93 85 73 36 86 49 7 53 85 46 2 53 36 43 38 13 43 30 12 41 69 70 91 84 77 35 51 13 33 92 75 16 18 69 26 49 35 93 72 16 88 84)

I am having trouble with my algorithm for the bubble sort part. When I click to run the numbers on my list show up correctly but then the display of the sorted numbers give me about 100 of just random numbers.

My algorithm has worked with other types of code when the computer simply ask the user to enter the number of numbers and the numbers in a previous assignment but this time we are using list and arrays.

I feel that my problem is something with my display statement or my variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// Sort numbers of the ARRAY_SIZE using Bubble Sort. 
void BubbleSort (int numbers[], int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE-i-1; ++j)
        {
            // Comparing consecutive data and switching values if value at j > j+1.
            if (numbers[j] > numbers[j+1])
            {
                numbers[j] = numbers[j]+numbers[j+1];
                numbers[j+1] = numbers[j]- numbers[j + 1];
                numbers[j] = numbers[j]- numbers[j + 1];
            }
        }
        // Value at n-i-1 will be maximum of all the values below this index.
    }   
        // Display the sorted data.
    cout<<" Sorted Data ";
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        cout << " / " << numbers[i];
}

//**************
//*Main function
//* 
//************
int main ()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 51; // constant so we can use it outside of main 
    int numbers[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int count = 0; // loop counter varible 
    ifstream inputFile; // input file stream object 

    //opening the file 
    inputFile.open("file.txt");

    //reading the numbers from the file then putting it into the array 
    while (count < ARRAY_SIZE && inputFile >> numbers [count])
    count ++;

    // closing file
    inputFile.close();

    // Displaying the unsorted numbers 
    cout << "The numbers are: " ;
    for (count = 0; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count ++)
    cout << numbers [count] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    // function for sorted numbers 
    BubbleSort(numbers, ARRAY_SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

I get a bunch of random numbers and I am supposed to get the numbers in order from least to greatest value. For example 2 / 7 / ect.

Your help is always appreciated in advance.

Comment: `for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE-i-1; ++j)` -- ok, I have to ask -- where did you get this idea for the inner loop for a bubble sort?  Shouldn't it be much simpler, i.e `for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE - 1; ++j)`?  The `i` shouldn't have any role here.

Comment: You've been told before about [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I was using a nested for loop.
The first loop will run on ‘i’ from 0 to n-1.
The second loop will run on ‘j’ from 0 to n-i-1.
Compare two consecutive values.
Switch the values if arr[j+1] <arr[j].
Return to main and display the result.

Comment: I removed the I but I still get the same thing. Do I remove i from the whole algorithm?

Comment: My suggestion is that you compare what you have to [some reference implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) and steal ideas from them

Comment: @Aspext -- Your idea for the inner loop is too convoluted for bubble sort.   If you did the bubble sort on paper, where does `i` play a role in the inner loop?  It doesn't.  All `i` is used for is the outer loop to control how many times to repeatedly start going through the list.  And was mentioned, why not look at a bubble sort implementation already coded -- you may find some that sets a flag when a swap occurs to control whether to keep sorting, but that's about it -- no funny inner loop using `i`.

Comment: How did this work then cpp.sh/56zll? I know its a different story because now we are using arrays but the algorithm is not wrong. I don't understand that my actual algorithm is the problem, do you mind explaining if it's wrong?

Comment: Here's the code hacked down to a MCVE: https://ideone.com/rUzj2n . May be some UB in there I don't see with this data set (`numbers[j]+numbers[j+1]` could overflow), and it takes more iterations than necessary, but it looks like it sorts. If you're getting garbage, it's from somewhere else.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The first `j` pass through sorts the highest value to the last slot, and each successive pass ensures one more slot toward the end of the array gets the best value for that slot.  Hence, the `i` keeps the inner loop from re-checking these already-fully-sorted values.  So it's an optimization.  Personally, I think it would be clearer if the `i` counted down, rather than counting up and having to compare `j` to a calculation, but that's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work I understand that my display was the problem and my argument worked with my parameters. 
I included this code in my main and I had my algorithm separated in the function.

```
cout << " The sorted numbers are: " ;
     for (auto num: numbers)
    {
        cout << num << ' ' ;
    }
```